# How to download image from url using picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso

I try to download image from url with help of picasso.But i cant do. i spend time in this more than two days. I tried async task that also failed. i tried alot. Please anyone help me.

```
protected static void postNotification(Intent intentAction, Context context,String msg,String url){

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentAction, Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);
   /* ImageDownloaderTask image = new ImageDownloaderTask();
    image.execute(url);*/
    Bitmap bitmapImage = retriveImage(url,context); //here only i want get that image.
    Log.d("Bitmap", String.valueOf(bitmapImage));//Its print only null
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tapn)
            .setContentTitle("Welcome!")
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmapImage))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .getNotification();

    mNotificationManager.notify(R.string.notification_number, notification);
}

private static Bitmap retriveImage(String url,Context c) {
    CacheTarget cacheTarget = new CacheTarget();
    Picasso.with(c)
            .load(url)
            .into(cacheTarget);
    return cacheTarget.getCacheBitmap();
}

private static class CacheTarget implements Target {
    private Bitmap cacheBitmap;
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)     {
        cacheBitmap = bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
    public Bitmap getCacheBitmap() {
        return cacheBitmap;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download and Save Images Using Picasso](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729976/download-and-save-images-using-picasso)

Comment: Thats different question..

Comment: the answers to that question provides the answer to your question too.. It is just that ListView is a access thing in that question.. But that does not matter as the main purpose is downloading the images..!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505290/preload-images-into-memory-disk-with-android-picasso

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Define where you want to save the file
String dirName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/myAppData/images";       
final File storageDir = new File(dirName);
            // Create directory
            if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                storageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            // Your image address. ex: "http://http://stackoverflow.com/myImages.jpg"
            String MY_IMAGE_URL = "The image url that you wish to download";  
                final ImageView profile = new ImageView(activity);
                final String img_path = storageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "myimage.jpg";
                Picasso.with(activity).load(MY_IMAGE_URL).into(profile, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // Save bitmap to local
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)profile.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                                File file = new File(img_path);
                                try {
                                    file.createNewFile();
                                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                            ostream.close();
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                }
             },100);
           }
        @Override
        public void onError() {
        }
 });
```

Hope this will help you :)