# How to make Picasso load images faster?

Tags: android, picasso, android-bitmap

I use Picasso (image downloading library for Android). [Picasso website](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

I charge my image like this:

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/myImage.png").into(imageView);
```

But, if `myImage.png` is too big, the download become slow. (With bad internet connection of course)

**How to make Picasso load images faster?**

**Can I just make the quality lower by Picasso? Or can I charge them "early" a few seconds before using them?**

Note that I cannot touch the file `myImage.png`

**---------------------**

**EDIT**

Any idea how to charge an image "early"? Should I use invisible view and load image into it, then use the same image in my View? How to add an image to cash (By Picasso always)?

Comment: if the image is too large from the source, you will still have to download it and process it within the app. There is no magic way of speeding the download of a large file if the internet is slow.

Answer (score 1):

**[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) optimize the image automatically loading a smaller version of the image into the ImageView**, but if the source image is "big", the load will become slow so i recommend to you optimize the source images.

Check this articles:

[Image Optimization](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization)

[Automating Image Optimization](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/automating-image-optimization/)

Answer (score 1):

No, Picasso loads a smaller version of that image into the view to use less memory, However it has to download the full source image before hand.

Consider uploading smaller images to have shorter download time, You may use multiple versions of your image:

```
image_thumbnail.png
image_small.png
image_medium.png
image_orginal.png
```

Download the thumbnail first and then download the small image, Use the bigger images for bigger views.

Yes it is possible to download them "early" but it's not recommend to waste the precious battery and bandwidth on mobile phones.

Comment: Any idea how to charge them "early"? Should I use invisible views or something?

Comment: @abinax Yes load them into a `Target` no need for invisible views

Comment: What is a Target please? example?

Comment: @abinax [Target is a Picasso Interface](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html), Forget it, You can use [fetch()](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#fetch--) to preload the image [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32850015/2970351)

Answer (score 1):

Picasso has no control over the server fulfilling the network request or the internet connection itself.  Using a service like Thumbor might help: https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor

Comment: Can I combine Picasso and thumbor?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add this to your android manifest

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

i use this to load videos faster, and it works for me ;) Maybe it'll also work for you

Comment: `android:hardwareAccelerated` is by default "`true`" so I guess it's not the solution to this question.